# Addition of two strings gives unintended result

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I would like to get a numeric value in a string which is in the format `1 111`.

I used a regex to extract it: 
`([0-9]*)\s([0-9]*)`

then I thought that I will obtain the correct result with this operation: 
`regex_result[1]*1000+regex_result[2]`

But actually I just have to addition them and I do not understand why.

```js
var str= "Bit rate                                 : 5 333 kb/s"

var bitrate= str.match(/Bit\srate\s*:\s([0-9]*)\s([0-9]*)\s/);
console.log(bitrate);

//attempted result, but incorrect code
console.log(bitrate[1]+bitrate[2]);

//attempted correct code, but wrong result
console.log(bitrate[1]*1000+bitrate[2]);
```

Comment: `bitrate[2]` is a string, not a number, so the resulting operation is concatenation, not addition.

Comment: You are right, it was just concatenation!

Answer (score -1):

Here, the second captured group *just so happens* to be 3 characters long, so multiplying the first captured group by 1000 and adding it to the second group will *just so happen* to produce the same result as plain concatenation.

But you have to add them together properly first. Your second attempt isn't working properly because the right-hand side of the `+` is a string, and a number `+` a string results in concatenation, not addition:

```js
var str = "Bit rate                                 : 5 333 kb/s"

var bitrate = str.match(/Bit\srate\s*:\s([0-9]*)\s([0-9]*)\s/);
console.log(bitrate[1] * 1000 + Number(bitrate[2]));
```

If the input isn't guaranteed to have exactly 3 digits in the second capturing group, the concatenation method won't work.

Answer (score -2):

You can parse them as ints instead of manipulating strings

```js
var str= "Bit rate                                 : 5 333 kb/s"

var bitrate= str.match(/Bit\srate\s*:\s([0-9]*)\s([0-9]*)\s/);
console.log(bitrate);

console.log(parseInt(bitrate[1] * 1000) + parseInt(bitrate[2]));
```

Comment: `parseInt(bitrate[1] * 1000)` the inner expression will already produce a number, no need to parse it.